# XUnit Test of Validator (FluentValidation): Way to Force Invalid DTO Instantiation?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xunit, fluentvalidation

I am generating unit tests for my validators built using Fluent Validation.  I want to simulate instances that I expect to receive from poorly formed incoming DTOs (such as null values, or bad enums).  However, I am unable to create a test data set that covers these possible scenarios because they are invalid objects.

Example, consider the following scenario:

```
public record EmailAddressDTO
{
    string Address;
    bool IsPrimary;
    EmailTypeEnum EmailType;
}

public enum EmailTypeEnum
{
    PERSONAL = 10,
    WORK = 20
}
```

I have a validator that checks that these are null or that the value coming in for the enum is valid.
Example:

```
public class EmailAddressValidator : AbstractValidator<EmailAddressDTO>
{
    public EmailAddressValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.Address).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Email Address is required");
        RuleFor(x => x.IsPrimary).NotNull().WithMessage("IsPrimary cannot be null");
        RuleFor(x => x.EmailType).IsInEnum().WithMesssage("Invalid Email Type");
    }
}
```

I want to unit test this validator by passing a record with null as Address or as IsPrimary - or with an out-of-scope number for the enum.  However, since this DTO is strictly typed, I can't instantiate an entity with the bad values.

I have attempted to create a record with null properties, but get an error. i.e.:

```
var emailAddress = new EmailAddressDTO
{
    Address = "Test@test.com",
    IsPrimary = null,  // Error - not possible
    EmailType = EmailTypeEnum.WORK
}
```

I have used explicit conversion for the enums like `(EmailTypeEnum)100` and that seems to work. I think I'm going crazy - but sometimes I think it passes validation like that.

Any ideas on how to generate bad data to pass in?

Comment: If that's DTO in a sense "something received by controler as a POST payload" than you should just set the `IsPrimary` property type to `bool?`. The same goes for the enum property if you want to validate not null value there to.

Comment: `IsPrimary` is a value type (`bool`) and would create an error before it reaches your validator if it wasn't provided or explicitly set null. So, that validation seems pretty superfluent. If you want a user friendly (-ier) error message, you may opt to make it optional `bool?` and then validating it to be not null ... which turns the mapping error into a validation error.